# C# Minimal API Agents

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I am trying to run multiple versions of a C# minimal API as agents. The logic being that I will programatically create multiple versions of my minimal API but each with a different port.

The manual way of doing this would be to run:

```
dotnet MyAgent.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5013
dotnet MyAgent.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5014
dotnet MyAgent.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5015
dotnet MyAgent.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:5016
```

In PowerShell.

Naturally this is impractical if you want 100 agents.

I have adapted some online code and come up with the following programatic way to do this:

```
//Start Agents

string projectPath = @"C:\StartAgent\StartAgent\StartAgent\bin\Debug\net6.0";
string dllName = "MyAgent.dll";
string port = "http://0.0.0.0:4015";
string port1 = "http://0.0.0.0:4016";

Console.WriteLine("Starting the app...");
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = projectPath;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
process.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add($"{dllName}");
process.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add($"--urls {port}");
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

var process1 = new Process();
process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = projectPath;
process1.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
process1.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add($"{dllName}");
process1.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add($"--urls {port1}");
process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


process.Start();
process1.Start();

process.Kill();
process1.Kill();
```

However, when I run the above, it keeps running the Agent on part 5000. And crashes when I try run the second agent as it too is on routed to port 5000.

This is weird because it is effectively running a command prompt, but does not take in the correct port argument. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say multiple versions, are they actually different or just the same but you want multiple instances? It seems like the latter.

Comment: _"Naturally this is impractical if you want 100 agents"_ Why? You can use loops and variables in PowerShell just like you can in C#.

Comment: It is multiple instances of the same code that are run. But they all need to be 100% isolated from each other.

I suppose I could create 100 agents in Powershell. I was thinking of that as a potential workaround. I think there is a complication with disposing of all of the agents as one would have to somehow keep track of all the instances. My knowledge in Powershell programming is extremely limited. Ideally I would prefer to stick to one programming language if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A powershell script should be abel to do the jobb for you

```
for($i = 5000; $i -lt 5100; $i++){
    $command = "dotnet MyAgent.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:" + $i;
    iex $command;
}
```

something like this might work?

Comment: Thx, how would I be able to terminate the agents when I am finished with them?